# car::vif Error in Math.data.frame ... non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: Interacts With, Other Predictors

Tags: r

I have a linear regression model (let's say called "reg") which includes an interaction variable. Ultimately, I want to calculate the variance inflation factors to check for multicollinearity.

I wanted to this by car::vif. As suggested, since there is an interaction variable, I am setting type = "predictor".

However, when I run this:

```
vif(reg, type = "predictor")
```

I encounter the error:

```
GVIFs computed for predictors
Error in Math.data.frame(list(GVIF = c(1.26950310090809, 1.39338672776922,  : 
  non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: Interacts With, Other Predictors
```

I don't know what's causing this. Any ideas?
It looks like the computation within vif is obstructed for some reason, but I have no idea why.

EDIT-Solved: Sorry, I realized my mistake now. I actually ran the following code and then got that error.

```
round(vif(reg, type = "predictor"),2)
```

The problem is vif(reg, type = "terms") returns a vector as output, whereas vif(reg, type = "predictor") returns a data.frame with non-numeric values in it.

Comment: Are you able to make this question reproducible? Sample data would be very useful, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Nope. I see your point. I'll try to do it sometime later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was also rounding the vif output. vif(reg, type = "terms") returns a vector as output, whereas vif(reg, type = "predictor") returns a data.frame with non-numeric values in it. round() doesn't work with the latter.